# How to get unique values from a column of Arrays PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I am trying to extract DISTINCT value of a column of arrays.

For example, If I have two rows:

```
{jonathan,michelle}
{jonathan,michael}
```

The output should be:

```
{jonathan,michelle,michael}
```

The output can be an array or a "virtual column" it is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unnest and aggregate back, ignoring duplicates:

```
select array_agg(distinct u.val) new_ar
from mytable t
cross join lateral unnest(t.ar) as u(val)
```

Note that this does not guarantee the order in which elements will appear in the final array (there are options, but you did not specify what you wanted in that regard).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b16cce555c99a16364c0fb70766cfac3)**:

```
| new_ar                      |
| :-------------------------- |
| {jonathan,michael,michelle} |
```

Comment: Sure, the order doesn´t matter but could you explain me your code if the table name is car and the column name is cityfrom.

Comment: @JonathanPrieto: just replace `mytable` with `car` and `ar` with `cityfrom`.

Comment: Worked Fine Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any idea, why if I add a where to the select, it doesn´t work? select array_agg(distinct u.val) new_usoauto from autos where 'particular'=ANY(usoauto) t cross join lateral unnest(t.usoauto) as u(val); @GMB

Comment: @JonathanPrieto: the `where` goes *after* the `from` clause (which itself includes the `lateral join`)

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Oh I just understood thank you! Here is the answer: Select array_agg(distinct u.val) new_usoauto from autos t cross join lateral unnest(t.usoauto) as u(val) where 'particular'= ANY(usoauto);

Answer (score 7):

The following seems to do the trick:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(unnest(tbl.ar)) FROM tbl
```

Comment: FWIW in my setup, `tbl` is not necessary in `tbl.ar`, i.e., this works for me: `SELECT DISTINCT(unnest(ar)) FROM tbl`

Comment: @sambecker yeah, you're right, `tbl` in `tbl.ar` is optional unless it's needed to resolve ambiguity in some more complex query.